# How to incorporate html table in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I used package 'sjPlot' to run some data analyses. For instant, function 'sjt.df' gives me a html table regarding simple description of variables. Then I created a Rmarkdown (see below). But when I clicked knit HTML/pdf, the result of the html table did not incorporate into the Rmarkdown. Rather, it popped up in my browser. How can I deal with that?

```
 {r}
library(sjPlot)
data(iris)
sjt.df(iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

See my tutorial [basics of sjt-functions](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjtbasics/), section *Knitr integration of HTML tables*.

If you just want to have the table, use `'r sjt.df(iris, no.output=TRUE)$knitr'` - (note that the ' have to be `).

The `no.output=TRUE` ensures that the table is not displayed in the viewer pane or browser, and the `$knitr` parameter contains the HTML-snippet that will be incorporated in RMarkdown.

If you also want to display the R-code, use

````
```{r eval=FALSE}
sjt.df(iris)
```
````

However, I guess that these tables are not converted well to PDF, only to HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. One more question, `sjp.lm(fit, type = "ma")` can be used to test model assumption. It produces several plots. How can I incorporate these plots in Rmarkdown/?

Comment: simply use `'''{r fig.width=7, fig.height=5, warning=FALSE}
sjp.lm(fit, type = "ma")
'''`

Comment: See also http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com and http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf