# knit sjplot as html output

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, sjplot

I am using [sjPlot::tab_xtab to create some tables in rmarkdown](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.8.9/topics/tab_xtab) (they look great!). However, the tables are generated as individual html pages in my browser, and not as a single html file. [Similar to this problem here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272066/how-to-incorporate-html-table-in-rmarkdown)

[According to the documentation](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/direct-integration-of-sjplot-tables-in-knitr-rmarkdown-documents-rstats/), we can use sjtab to knit tables into a html file: (this is what I want)

````
```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
 
efc %>% 
  group_by(e16sex, c172code) %>% 
  select(e42dep, n4pstu, e16sex, c172code) %>% 
  sjtab(fun = "xtab")
```
````

I don't know how to incorporate this sjtab into my user function to generate the plots.
I also [looked through this documentation](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/news/index.html), but could not find the solution. Right now, I have to take a screen shot of each table that appears my browser and paste the tables together. :(

**Problem:**
I want to have all the tables in a single file (html, pdf or word) so that I can scroll down the file to view all the tables at once.

Could someone please let me know how I can render each of the tables into a [single html file](https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-08-01/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/sjtbasic.html)?

**Here is the code from my rmarkdown file. It should run with no error.**

````
---
title: "testChi"
author: "g"
date: "10/15/2021"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(pander)



# cols <- svy_final %>% select(matches("Q44_[[:digit:]]")) %>% names(.)
cols <- mtcars %>% select(matches("mpg|cyl|disp")) %>% names(.)

create_plots <- function(dat,title_name) {

  # school <- enquo()
 for (i in cols) {
    plt <- sjPlot::tab_xtab(
      var.row =  dat$gear,
      var.col = dat[[i]],
      show.row.prc = TRUE,
      var.labels = c("gear size", i),
      title = title_name
    )
    # return(out)
    print(plt)
  }
}

```




```{r loop_print, results = 'asis',error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

create_plots(mtcars, 'gear and stuff') %>% pander()


```
````

Comment: What is a single html-file? What do you want: one table  — one html file with one page?

Comment: @manro I want all the tables in a single output (html, pdf or word)

Comment: Do you use RStudio?

Comment: @manro yup, I am running this in a rmarkdown file in Rstudio

Comment: I haven't yet launched your markdown. Full of errors.

Comment: That is odd, it runs perfectly for me.

Comment: In console your code works nice, but in the markdown i can't reproduce oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your markdown running and I can see the problem.

For me the workaround below worked.
It is basically your code, just that each plot isn't called in the loop, but saved to a list. Afterwards you just call each plot separately from the list `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]`, `l[[3]]` without using a loop.

Your problem seems  to appear whenever you call the plots inside a loop.

```````
---
title: "testChi"
author: "g"
date: "10/15/2021"
output:
  html_document: default
---

``````{r packages, include = F}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(pander)
```


```{r tables, , print = F, echo = F, results="asis"}

cols <- mtcars %>% select(matches("mpg|cyl|disp")) %>% names(.)
dat <- mtcars
title_name <- 'gear and stuff'

l = list()
i = 1;

for (x in cols) {
      plt <- sjPlot::tab_xtab(
      var.row =  dat$gear,
      var.col = dat[[x]],
      show.row.prc = TRUE,
      var.labels = c("gear size", x),
      title = title_name)
      l[[i]] <- plt
      i = i+1
}

l[[1]]
l[[2]]
l[[3]]

```
```````

The **result** ( all plots below each other):

[image]

Here is also a version without having to call each element separately:

```````
---
title: "testChi"
author: "g"
date: "10/15/2021"
output:
  html_document: default
---

``````{r packages, include = F}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(pander)
```


```{r tables, , print = F, echo = F, results="asis"}

cols <- mtcars %>% select(matches("mpg|cyl|disp")) %>% names(.)
dat <- mtcars
title_name <- 'gear and stuff'

i = 1;
c <- character()

for (x in cols) {
      plt <- sjPlot::tab_xtab(
      var.row =  dat$gear,
      var.col = dat[[x]],
      show.row.prc = TRUE,
      var.labels = c("gear size", x),
      title = title_name)
      c <-  paste(c, plt$knitr)
}

knitr::raw_html(c)


```
```````

I think in general you have to avoid separate print statements on the return object of `tab_xtab()`, since it is always a whole `html` page. While `$knitr` from the return object isn't a whole html page, but instead only the html code for the tables.

Another version to fit exactly the initial example with a function:

````
  ---
title: "testChi"
author: "g"
date: "10/15/2021"
output:
  html_document: default
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(pander)


cols <- mtcars %>% select(matches("mpg|cyl|disp")) %>% names(.)

create_plots <- function(dat,title_name) {

 c <- character()
 for (i in cols) {
    plt <- sjPlot::tab_xtab(
      var.row =  dat$gear,
      var.col = dat[[i]],
      show.row.prc = TRUE,
      var.labels = c("gear size", i),
      title = title_name
    )
  c <-  paste(c, plt$knitr)

 }
 knitr::raw_html(c)

}

```

```{r loop_print, results = 'asis',error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
create_plots(mtcars, 'gear and stuff')
```

```{r loop_print2, results = 'asis',error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
create_plots(mtcars, 'other stuff')
```
````

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I have hundreds of graphs, is there a way to print them out without calling them explicitly like you have?

Comment: Yes, sure. I added this for at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: One small problem--I am feeding in different datasets, and different titles, so I find myself copy pasting this loop many times. I am trying to alter your solution back to my user function, but keep getting errors

Comment: ok, wait, I'll show you how you can adjust it to your function (see in the answer)

Comment: I think basically you have to avoid separate print statements on the return object of tab_xtab, since it is always a whole html page. While $knitr from the return object isn't a whole html page, but instead only the html code for the tables.